# Salt Stack: templating in SLS files

Tags: templates, firefox, selenium, salt-stack

I'm using Salt Stack for deployment purposes and need to deploy different browser versions to Selenium Grid nodes (e.g. Firefox 29.0 and 30.0). So from the Salt perspective I would like to use the following in **top.sls**:

```
base:
  'firefox29':
    - firefox
      - version: 29.0

  'firefox30':
    - firefox
      - version: 30.0
```

In this example we reuse **firefox.sls** state:

```
firefox:
  pkg.installed:
    - skip_verify: True
    - version: {{ version }}
```

I tried SLS files above with recent Salt (2014.1.7) and they are simply ignored (nothing is installed). When I remove **version** from **firefox.sls** it installs the latest Firefox.

Is it possible to somehow parameterize SLS states like in my example? I saw an issue on Github (https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/8878) describing the ways to do that with Jinja macro but didn't manage to use it for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do this with a jinja macro:

```
firefox:
  pkg.installed:
  {% if grains['id'] == 'firefox29' %}
    - version: 29.0
  {% elif grains['id'] == 'firefox30' %}
    - version: 30.0
  {% endif %}
```

If it gets any more complicated than that you should invest in learning pillars and keeping this sort of logic there.  http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/

Comment: Yes, I actually did almost the same but with **'firefox30' in grains['id']**.

Comment: Great to hear!  Would you mind marking my answer as a solution?